# Custom action GetUrl

Tags: magento-1.9, module

Ok, this is the follow up to a other question of mine. I just can't figure out the last detail.

I created a custom extension to set a order status to "Ready for Pickup". The button shows and is clickable but does not generate the correct action.

**/app/code/local/Mymodule/Pickup/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Mymodule_Pickup>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Mymodule_Pickup>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
         <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_view>Mymodule_Pickup_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View</sales_order_view>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/Mymodule/Pickup/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
class Mymodule_Pickup_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action

public function pickupAction()
{
  $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
  $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
  $order->setStatus("pickup_ready");
  $order->save();
  // redirect to your sales order view page back
}
?>
```

**/app/code/local/Mymodule/Pickup/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/View.php**

```
<?
class Mymodule_Pickup_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View 
{
public function  __construct() {

parent::__construct();

$order = $this->getOrder();

    $this->_addButton('inform_pickup', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Custom Pickup Button'),
        'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getPickupUrl($order) . '\')',
    ));
}

public function getPickupUrl($order)
{
   return $this->getUrl('pickup/adminhtml_index/pickup', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
}
}
?>
```

The problem is that my

```
return $this->getUrl('pickup/adminhtml_index/pickup', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
```

is not working. It redirects me to a front page 404. What am I doing wrong in this Url?

### UPDATE

Added /app/code/local/Mymodule/Pickup/etc/adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <pickup translate="title" module="pickup">
                                    <title>Pickup</title>
                                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                                </pickup>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

Comment: Have you installed the latest security patch : SUPEE-6788 ?

Comment: Yes I have, but creating this from new, so not like it worked before

Comment: The reason Prateek is asking the question is that the patch disables the use of custom admin url's, you should be basing your requests off the admin router http://blog.husseycoding.co.uk/2015/11/updating-your-modules-for-supee-6788.html

Comment: Not sure what the adminhtml.xml is good for. I don't want a admin menu, I just want the button to change my order status. I am guessing the problem might be in the config.xml. Will add it above

Answer (score 0):

you are missing Adminhtml in controller file

```
<?php
class Mymodule_Pickup_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action

public function pickupAction()
{
  $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
  $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
  $order->setStatus("pickup_ready");
  $order->save();
  // redirect to your sales order view page back
}
?>
```

for router add in your config.xml out sdie the `<global></global>` tag

```
<admin>
        <routers>
          <pickup>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
              <module>Mymodule_Pickup</module>
              <frontName>pickup</frontName>
            </args>
          </pickup>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

Comment: Mistake corrected but still the same result. Redirects me to frontend with a 404. The link in the addressbar: http://myshop.com/index.php/beheer/adminhtml_index/pickup/order_id/10851/key/xxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: config.xml you add router for admin?

Comment: the mention acl for system configuration. update the answer check it

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of issue in module.

**Controller name should follow magento pattern.**

`Mymodule_Pickup_IndexController`  should be `Mymodule_Pickup_AdminhtmlIndexController`

### Rules:

**If The controller location is**

`app/code/MOudleCodePool(local/Community/Core)/[YOurModuleNameSpace]/[YourModuleName]/controllers/RestofPathTillControllerFile/[ControllerName]Controller.php`

**Then class**

`[YOurModuleNameSpace]_[YourModuleName]_[RestOfPathofControllerTillControllerfolder]_ControllerName{Controller}`

But for magento security purpose ,you need use  magento rewrite  adminhtml controller  pattern for add new controller.

see [Supee-9788](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details)

Comment: Amit, its SUPEE-6788 .